# C# -- Create Managed Array from Pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to create a Managed Array of doubles from an array of bytes.  I have the problem working currently, but I wanted to optimize. Here's some code that I would like to work:

```
private unsafe static double[] _Get_Doubles(byte[] _raw_data)
{
    double[] ret;
    fixed (byte* _pd = _raw_data)
    {
        double* _pret = (double*)_pd;
        ret = (double[])*_pret; //FAILURE
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to cope with these problems.

-Aaron

Comment: In general when dealing with Interop, the Marshaller is your friend, at your service at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal. I don't know though what specifically you need for using arrays. You can, however, access arrays with pointer arithmetic. Maybe this hints you into the right direction.

Comment: @daGhost -- I'm certainly aware of accessing arrays with pointers, but I'll have to look into marshalling a managed array.  Thanks.

Comment: @Limited Thing (Please don't call me daGhost again): If you can access the array elements with pointers, you can copy the values into a managed array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just now, I thought that `stackalloc` would be the right way, but it fails.  Most importantly, I now know that it was doomed to fail.  There is no way to do what I want to do.

This can be seen by restating the question:

How can I create a managed array around an 'unsafe' array?

Since a managed array has header information (because it's a class around a chuck of memory), it requires more space in memory than the array itself.  So, the answer is:

Allocate space before (and/or after? depending on the way managed arrays are stored in memory) the array itself and put the managed information (length, (et cetera)) around the 'unsafe' array.

This is not easily possible because to guarantee that there is data enough around the array is shaky at best.  In my particular example there may be enough space for it because a managed byte[] is passed in meaning that there is data around the array, but to assert that the same data is appropriate for managed double[] is dubious at best, but most likely erroneous, and to change the data to make it appropriate for managed double[]  is nefarious.

[EDIT]

It looks like `Marshal.Copy` is the way to go here.  Create a new array and let Marshal copy them (hoping that he will be quicker than me, or that perhaps at some later date, he will be quicker):

```
var ret = new double[_raw_data.Length / sizeof(double)];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(new System.IntPtr(_pret), ret, 0, ret.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the key things to notice about the code you have posted is that there is no way to know how many items are pointed to by the return value, and a managed array needs to know how big it is.  You can return a `double*` or create a `new double[XXX]` and copy the values or even (if the count is constant) create a `struct` with a `public fixed double _data[2];` member and cast the raw data to that type.

Comment: That is basically what I wound up doing.  I created the double array with a fixed length, then copied my values in there one at a time.  It would be nice to, in a C++ way, not allocate the new double array.  Yeah, a struct with a double[] and a byte[] set to overlap like the al, ax, and eax registers, but the overhead of creating a struct might be more than what I'm doing...which might make you think, why on earth would you want to be so convoluted in your array-copying?  To which I answer `   '.